# dataframe from dictionary of lists

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

Is there a way to achieve following with purely pandas methods or is it actually more reasonable to rearrange the dictionary itself first?

Initial dictionary:

```py
data_json = {'a':[{'aa':1,'bb':2,'cc':3},
                  {'aa':2,'bb':2,'cc':3},
                  {'aa':3,'bb':2,'cc':3}],
             'b':[{'beta':22,'alpha':23,'gamma':24},
                  {'gamma':24,'beta':25,'alpha':26},
                  {'alpha':34,'beta':35,'gamma':36}]}
```

And I would like to get a dataframe where column names would be nested dictionary keys:

```py
  aa bb cc alpha beta gamma
1  1  2  3    23   22    24
2  2  2  3    26   25    24
3  3  2  3    34   35    36
```

Trying:

```py
aaa = pd.DataFrame(data_json)
foo = lambda x: pd.Series([i for i in x.items()])
bbb=pd.concat([aaa['a'].apply(foo),aaa['b'].apply(foo)],axis=1)
```

Gives me

```py
   0  1  2     0    1     2
1  1  2  3    23   22    24
2  2  2  3    26   25    24
3  3  2  3    34   35    36
```

But now I'm stuck because the column names are duplicated [0,1,2,0,1,2] and I cannot use just the

```py
bbb.rename(columns={0:'a',1:'b',...})
```

As I said I do not mind reordering the initial dictionary, but I'd like the whole thing be as clean as possible.

Comment: Do you mind adding the output dataframe you're expecting please?

Comment: Sure, not sure how to format it properly, though

Comment: The way you have it is fine. So basically you no longer care about 'a' or 'b', but the other of the item in the value list matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would load both 'a' and 'b' separately and join them (merge them on index):

```
pd.DataFrame(data_json['a']).join(pd.DataFrame(data_json['b']))


   aa  bb  cc  alpha  beta  gamma
0   1   2   3     23    22     24
1   2   2   3     26    25     24
2   3   2   3     34    35     36
```

---

Another way with a loop in case you don't know how many `data_json.keys()` you have, then using `pd.concat` since it's more convenient with a list. Note that I'm using
`sorted(data_json)` so I can get `a` before `b`:

```
list_df = []
for k in sorted(data_json):
    list_df.append(pd.DataFrame(data_json[k]))
pd.concat(list_df, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use `concat`. Note:

```
In [11]: pd.DataFrame(data_json['a'])
Out[11]: 
   aa  bb  cc
0   1   2   3
1   2   2   3
2   3   2   3

In [12]: pd.DataFrame(data_json['b'])
Out[12]: 
   alpha  beta  gamma
0     23    22     24
1     26    25     24
2     34    35     36
```

So simply:

```
In [13]: pd.concat((pd.DataFrame(v) for v in data_json.values()), axis=1)
Out[13]: 
   alpha  beta  gamma  aa  bb  cc
0     23    22     24   1   2   3
1     26    25     24   2   2   3
2     34    35     36   3   2   3

In [14]:
```

Comment: Thanks for more general solution.